# Can't find my horse?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

While on a mission to collect chicken eggs, I stopped vaguely close to a village and made a pit to put my tamed horse in it. I flew out of it and went back to my castle. I've searched for two days, but I can't find my horse. Any suggestions? Is there a command for locating the nearest horse by any chance?

Comment: Might just be easier to find another one.

Comment: "Flew" out of it? Where you in creative? If so couldn't you just spawn another one?

Answer (score 4):

Can you not find the pit or can you not find the horse in the pit? Please make your question more specific.

Command to teleport all horses nearby to you:

```
/tp @e[type=EntityHorse] @p
```

Comment: I put the horse in the pit, and I can't find the pit.

Comment: THANKYOUTHANKYOUTHANKYOU!!!!!!!!!!!!!! The command brought my horse back!!!!!

Comment: If this answered your question, you can select it as the correct one by pressing the check mark next to the answer.